# User not authorized to access mobile first platform operations console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-console

We installed WAS liberty and we used 'Server configuration tool' for 'server and runtime' deployments (on linux).  It builds and deploys successfully

when we type in http://localhost:9080/worklightconsole using default user 'demo/demo'  it throws an error

"User not authorized to log in the console"

Please help us to resolve this error

Thanks
Sathish Kumar

Comment: In fact we tried by deleting both 'server configuration' and 'runtime environment' and redid it.  But no change

Comment: Upload your messages.log as well as server.xml so they could be inspected.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to upload files.  But messages.log has the following error

[7/20/15 18:46:14:673 IST] 000001bc .ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl A CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user demo while invoking worklightconsole on /index.html. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].

and what info do you require from server.xml?  if possible I can search that and post it.  I could see both 'username' and 'password' are set to 'demo'

Comment: Dropbox, pastebin, Google Docs, ... plenty of services are available at your disposal.

Comment: Do you have gmail or yahoo id so that I can send the files ?

Comment: No. Please upload them. You can sanitize them (change names, add ****) if you have sensitive information there.

Comment: can you initiate a chat with me ?  because I could not initiate a chat as my reputation is too low and I don't know how to use dropbox and other utilities

and I see the following in server.xml

    241         <application-bnd>
    242             <security-role name="worklightadmin">
    243                 <user name="demo"/>
    244 
    245             </security-role>

Comment: No. Upload the files.

Comment: Is this resolved or does it still happen? If it still happens please provide the requested files as you have done in another question of yours.

Comment: Sathish Kumar Please respond!

Comment: The issue was resolved by restarting server on WAS (ex simpleServer)

Comment: Sathish, please either write it as an answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the liberty server had to be re-started in order to take into account the username and password defined in the deployed MobileFirst Server's server.xml file.

After restarting the server, the username and password were then accepted in the login screen.